# php Undefined index when I dont use a redundant if statement

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I want to access and change one of the values from an integer to a string using a helper function. The code below works but if I remove the if statement which I dont really need it gives me a Undefined index error on the helper code

$stories = multidimensional array in this format

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(4) 
        { 
            ["code"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["user_name"]=> string(4) "Dave" 
            ["name"]=> string(11) "project one" 
            ["sample_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
        }
    }
```

to access the array I am using

```
foreach($stories as $key => $subarray) {
        if(array_key_exists('code', $subarray)){
            //if($stories[$key]['code'] > 0){        
                $stories[$key]['code'] = task_priority_text($stories[$key]['code']);
            //};
        }
}
```

Commenting the code in this way throws the error while uncommenting gives a clean result.

Here is the helper function which I have used elsewhere and works well

```
if ( ! function_exists('task_priority_text'))
{
    function task_priority_text($priority = FALSE)
    {
        $options = array('0' => 'Urgent', '1' => 'High', '2' => 'Medium', '3' => 'Low', '4' => 'Minimal');

    if($priority !== FALSE)
        return $options[$priority];
    else 
        return $options;
    }
}
```

How do I get ride of this if statement?

---

EDIT

here is the error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: Medium
Filename: helpers/tasks_helper.php
Line Number: 70
```

line 70 of the helper is

```
return $options[$priority];
```

Comment: clearly it wasn't redundant then

Comment: Put the error in the question

Comment: Undefined index, *warning* not *error*

Comment: I'm curious why you have the nested foreach with `foreach($subarray as $subkey => $subsubarray) {` when you never reference either `$subkey` or `$subsubarray`? Is it just so you can run a foreach on `$subarray`?

Comment: @larsAnders yer your right. This can be removed and it does not affect anything. Its a leftover from a copy and paste of code. I will edit to remove this

Comment: In your loop is $stories[$key]['code'] an integer? I think this might already contain the string 'Medium' when it it passed to the function.

Comment: In fact I can see what is happening, each item is being looped over twice because of the extra loop. So the second time it is set to 'Medium' removing the redundant loop should fix it.

Comment: @jd182 yep $stories[$key]['code'] is an integer

Comment: @jd182 perfect. Put this as an answer and I will mark as correct. Thanks. Thats what you get for copy-pasting old code

Comment: You are confusing yourself by using $stories[$key] inside the loop. Clearer to just use $subarray whenever you want to refer to that entity.
Also might want your $options array to be static and not recreate it every time you run your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over each item in the array multiple times. The 'outer' loop runs once for every item in the array, then the 'inner' loop (which someone else pointed out is redundant) runs again for every item in the $subarray variable.

```
foreach($stories as $key => $subarray) {
    foreach($subarray as $subkey => $subsubarray) {
        if(array_key_exists('code', $subarray)){
        //if($stories[$key]['code'] > 0){        
            $stories[$key]['code'] = task_priority_text($stories[$key]['code']);
        //};
        }
    }
}
```

This would be a better way of doing it:

```
foreach($stories as $story)
{
   $story['code'] = task_priority_text($story['code']);
}
```